# Queues not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm having trouble with queues when sending email. Emails are sent when I use the send method:

```
Mail::send
```

When I switch to the queue method and configure the jobs table, QUEUE_DRIVER and the failed_jobs table, all the jobs in the queue end up in the failed_jobs table. I haven't touched anything on the queue.php file.

Running on Windows 7 as my developer environment.

PHP Version 5.6.15

Does this feature use curl(because phpinfo shows that it is enabled)?

Code:

**.env file**

QUEUE_DRIVER=database

**Mailer**

```
Mail::queue('emails.orderEmail',
      [
      'user' => Auth::user()
    ], function ($m) {
        $m->from($this->business->email, $this->business->business_name);
        $m->to($this->recipientEmail);
        $m->subject($this->subject);
        $m->replyTo($this->business->email, $this->name);
      });
```

I'm running this artisan command (tried queue:work as well to avail):

```
 php artisan queue:listen --tries=3
```

Comment: Delete your log file, and run your script again and see the log file, wonders eh? You most likely have syntax error somewhere. You can also open up `failed_jobs` table and see the stack trace there.

Comment: @Kyslik I've a php SERVER variable called STORE_ID that seems to produce an exception error. Is it not accessible when sending via queue? [2017-06-23 12:33:22] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: STORE_ID' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Server1\app\ShippingSettings.php:18
Stack trace:

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass that STORE_ID session variable to the mail view.

```
Mail::queue('emails.orderEmail',
  [
  'user' => Auth::user(),
  'store_id' => session('STORE_ID')
], function ($m) {
```

Comment: The STORE_ID SERVER variable is unavailable to my models as well not just the email view so it's not working. I may need to rethink how I'm availing the STORE_ID throughout the application.